# Dropdown on Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown and items using Bootstrap, but when I code a list item it doesn't appear.

See code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dd-mneus" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.bootply.com/lEZRcmZQol

Comment: What do you mean by code item? Would you mind creating jsfiddle for us to investigate your issue?

Comment: I think he means it doesn't drop the list as expected.  Check out this plunker -- it doesn't work there: http://plnkr.co/edit/10bMstgY9WYSWSjMf1cD?p=preview and this jsfiddle -- doesn't work there either.  I added the externally required JS. https://jsfiddle.net/7gr6f9zt/

Comment: @Aibrean yes this work but why this can not work when i use it..

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja see this link bootply.com/lEZRcmZQol as aibrean post it

Comment: Have you include the bootstrap js file correctly ? Have you any js error ?

Comment: @daylight exactly.. so where is the problem

Comment: Drop list wasn't firing.  Okay, I updated on plunker to have Jquery also and now it works.  That's the missing piece I think.

Comment: @YenneInfo i add only css like this .. <link href='css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>

Comment: @daylight now working . thanks :)

Comment: You need to include the bootstrap js file after the jquery js file. It's very important

Comment: @YenneInfo yes i added now its working.

Comment: @scorpio i posted the solution as an answer so someone else would see what the resolution was.  Please select as answer if you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following plunker shows the original code with working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/10bMstgY9WYSWSjMf1cD?p=preview

The problem is that jQuery wasn't loaded.  Loading the jQuery fixes the problem since Bootstrap js is dependent upon it.

Note that the jquery ref needs to be loaded before the bootstrap js is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dd-mneus" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">List item</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap for create tab control but never used it to create drop down list. so why don't you try in simple asp.net drop down list

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="yourID" runat="server">

     <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>

     <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>

     <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>  

      </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: this works perfect for me try your code in simple page(only drop down list and button) then you can figure what's wrong with your code